# scraping odds with selenium after mouse over

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

from the webpage of oddsportal, I want to scrape the odds of **Pinnacle** bookmaker only:
https://www.oddsportal.com/football/russia/premier-league/spartak-moscow-akhmat-grozny-dI0Fo2oa/#1X2;2
[image]

the data appear only when I mouse over the odd

I did using selenium this but got error:

```
a = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[./a[contains(text(),"Pinnacle")]]/div[2]')

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(a)
hover.perform()
```

I tried to find a solution with **bs4** and **requests** but I can't find a link to scrape it from a particular page:
[image]

for example, in this page, data can be found in https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/match-event/1-1-dI0Fo2oa-1-2-yj972.dat
I can use this link with requests but the issue is when I automate the scraping and use the base url, the part `dI0Fo2oa` from the base url can be known (from the webpage url), but I don't know how to add the part (or from where to find) the part: `yj972`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around that I tried to solve your problem

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


options = ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.oddsportal.com/football/russia/premier-league/spartak-moscow-akhmat-grozny-dI0Fo2oa/#1X2;2"

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 500);")
time.sleep(2)
element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[9]/div[2]').click()

time.sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "flex text-xs border-b h-9"})
target_element = None
for i in container:
    if i.findNext('p', attrs={"class": "pl-4 height-content max-mm:hidden"}).text == 'Pinnacle':
        target_element = i

data_dict = {}

temp1 = target_element.findNext('div', attrs={"class": "gap-1 mt-2"}).text.split(': ')
data_dict[temp1[0]] = temp1[1]

temp2 = target_element.findNext('div', attrs={"class": "flex flex-row gap-3"}).find_all('div', {"class": "flex flex-col gap-1"})

data_dict[target_element.findNext('h3').text] = {
    "date_time": [i.text for i in temp2[0].find_all('div')],
    "value": [i.text for i in temp2[1].find_all('div')],
    "change": [i.text for i in temp2[2].find_all('div')]
}
print(data_dict)
```

and this is the output of data_dict:

```
{'Opening odds': '25 Mar, 14:131.51', 'Odds movement': {'date_time': ['01 Apr, 20:22', '01 Apr, 20:22', '01 Apr, 20:08', '01 Apr, 20:08', '01 Apr, 19:52', '01 Apr, 19:52', '01 Apr, 19:50', '01 Apr, 19:50', '01 Apr, 19:49', '01 Apr, 19:49', '01 Apr, 19:39', '01 Apr, 19:39', '01 Apr, 19:30', '01 Apr, 19:30', '01 Apr, 19:27', '01 Apr, 19:27', '01 Apr, 19:23', '01 Apr, 19:23', '01 Apr, 19:19', '01 Apr, 19:19', '01 Apr, 18:57', '01 Apr, 18:57', '01 Apr, 18:49', '01 Apr, 18:49', '01 Apr, 18:43', '01 Apr, 18:43', '01 Apr, 18:39', '01 Apr, 18:39', '01 Apr, 18:37', '01 Apr, 18:37', '01 Apr, 18:36', '01 Apr, 18:36', '01 Apr, 18:33', '01 Apr, 18:33', '01 Apr, 18:32', '01 Apr, 18:32', '01 Apr, 18:20', '01 Apr, 18:20', '01 Apr, 17:30', '01 Apr, 17:30'], 'value': ['1.52', '1.54', '1.55', '1.57', '1.56', '1.58', '1.57', '1.61', '1.60', '1.61', '1.57', '1.56', '1.58', '1.57', '1.58', '1.59', '1.57', '1.58', '1.60', '1.61'], 'change': ['-0.02', '-0.01', '-0.02', '+0.01', '-0.02', '+0.01', '-0.04', '+0.01', '-0.01', '+0.04', '+0.01', '-0.02', '+0.01', '-0.01', '-0.01', '+0.02', '-0.01', '-0.02', '-0.01', '+0.10']}}
```

I hope It's helpful.

Comment: thanks, why you did the click on this xpath exactly ? I need data from the Pinnacle only```element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[9]/div[2]').click()```

Comment: because that's the XPath for the Pinnacle only, see the pointer on your first image, it's the path of that element of the Pinnacle row. We need to click there so that the data for Pinnacle gets loaded into the HTML.